# display various chart value and tool tip

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

I have the bar chart and I want to show chart for the value data and the tool tip with data1 with chart js

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Global Options:
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'dodgerblue';
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

// Data with datasets options
var data = {
    labels: ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"],
      datasets: [
        {
            label: "Ice Cream Prices ",
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: [
                'moccasin',
                'saddlebrown',
                'lightpink'],
            data: [11, 9, 4],
             data1: [111, 19, 14]
        }
    ]
};

var options = {
tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem) {
                return "$" + Number(data1) + " and so worth it !";
            }
        }
    },
        title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Ice Cream Truck',
                  position: 'bottom'
              },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
};

// Chart declaration:
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #333;
}

#barChart{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
<!--       Chart.js Canvas Tag -->
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have displying chart for the data and tried to display tooltip with data1 values.
But not able to display.now getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `tooltips.callback.label` function as follows:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
      const data1 = data.datasets[0].data1;
      return "$" + data1[tooltipItem.index] + " and so worth it !";
    }
  }
}
```

> For further information, consult the chapter [Label Callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) from Chart.js v2.9.4 documentation.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("barChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Global Options:
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'dodgerblue';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;

// Data with datasets options
var data = {
  labels: ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Ice Cream Prices ",
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: [
      'moccasin',
      'saddlebrown',
      'lightpink'
    ],
    data: [11, 9, 4],
    data1: [111, 19, 14]
  }]
};

var options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
        const data1 = data.datasets[0].data1;
        return "$" + data1[tooltipItem.index] + " and so worth it !";
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Ice Cream Truck',
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
};

// Chart declaration:
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #333;
}

#barChart{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do the same for https://jsfiddle.net/m6k9cbzq/1/ displaying value for the whole bar now not the exact value .Please help

Comment: You have to define `tooltips.mode: 'index'` and slightly change the `tooltips.callback.label` function (see https://jsfiddle.net/r4e2b7st/).